# programming with dplyr::arrange in dplyr v.0.7

Tags: r, dplyr, nse, non-standard-evaluation

I am trying to get my head around the new implementations in `dplyr` with respect to programming and non standard evaluation. So the verb_ functions are replaced by `enquo` of the argument and then applying `!!` in the regular verb function. Translating `select` from old to new works fine, the following function give similar results:

```
select_old <- function(x, ...) {
  vars <- as.character(match.call())[-(1:2)]
  x %>% select(vars)
}

select_new <- function(x, ...) {
  vars <- as.character(match.call())[-(1:2)]
  vars_enq <- enquo(vars)
  x %>% select(!!vars_enq)
}
```

However when I try to use `arrange` in the new programming style I'll get an error:

```
arrange_old <- function(x, ...) {
  vars <- as.character(match.call())[-(1:2)]
  x %>% arrange_(vars)
}

arrange_new <- function(x, ...){
  vars <- as.character(match.call())[-(1:2)]
  vars_enq <- enquo(vars)
  x %>% arrange(!!vars_enq)
}

mtcars %>% arrange_new(cyl)     
# Error in arrange_impl(.data, dots) : 
#  incorrect size (1) at position 1, expecting : 32
```

32 is obviously the number of rows of `mtcars`, the inner function of `dplyr` apparently expects a vector of this length. My questions are why does the new programming style not traslate for `arrange` and how to it then in the new style.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are overthinking it. Use the appropriate function to deal with `...`. No need to use `match.call` at all (also not in the old versions, really).

```
arrange_new <- function(x, ...){
  dots <- quos(...)
  x %>% arrange(!!!dots)
}
```

Of course this function does the exact same as the normal `arrange`, but I guess you are just using this as an example.

You can write a `select` function in the same way.

The `arrange_old` should probably have looked something like:

```
arrange_old <- function(x, ...){
  dots <- lazyeval::lazy_dots(...)
  x %>% arrange_(.dots = dots)
}
```

Comment: Thanks, overlooked that part in the vignntte, I am afraid.

Comment: It's not all that clear, actually. But looking at the source of e.g. `dplyr:::select.data.frame` helps.

Answer (score 1):

You don't actually need rlang in this situation.  This will work:

```
my_arrange <- function(x, ...) arrange(x, ...)

# test
DF <- data.frame(a = c(2, 2, 1, 1), b = 4:1)
DF %>% my_arrange(a, b)
```

Comment: Ow wow. Does this work because `arrange`  applies rlang internally?

Comment: This uses just base R and works with any R function.  rlang is not involved. 
 It is not specific to dplyr.